# Excel's RTD to get data from public websites?

Tags: excel, rtd

Is there a way to use Excel's RTD function to get data from an publicly-available stock ticker such as Google Finance or Yahoo Finance?

I know that for Schwab's "ThinkOrSwim", I'd say something like:
`=RTD("tos.rtd", , "BID", "AAPL")`

...but I can't seem to create a Schawb account. (That's a separate question.)

I tried replacing "tos.rtd" with "google.rtd" and "yahoo.rtd". I just got #N/A errors, so it was either a dumb guess or there's something else I'm doing wrong.